# Getting 404 for PUT and DELETE request on IIS 7.5 server 2008

Tags: javascript, php, http, iis

It's been several days I'm fighting to solve the PUT,DELETE issues in my web app.

- I'm using REST server (php)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5
- My server is a dedicated server hosted at contabo company in germany
- Client side using js (sencha touch)
- GET,POST works fine

my domain and my database on the same server, I have tried many suggestion using the net:

- Enable verbs in "Handler Mappings"
- Webdav not installed
- Create web.config:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>  <system.webServer>   
>    <httpProtocol>
>      <customHeaders>
>        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example.com" />      
>      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" />
>      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
>        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*" />
>      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />      
>      </customHeaders>
>    </httpProtocol>
>  </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```

I also tryied to medify the: 'applicationHost.config' (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config):

```
<add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
<add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

but nothing :-(

- I also have laptop with win7 and IIS 7.5 and no problem it's working great.
- I just don't know how to fix it in my server?

Thank you for advice

Comment: have you tried tracing the request with Firebug? Is there any difference between the network trace for your local machine, and the trace for your server?

Comment: I'm using firebug all the time, It just says: PUT http://xxxxxx.com/php/customers.php/13?_dc=1417022337273    404 Not Found 4.6s

Comment: When you do a GET and POST, is it the same URL as in the PUT and DELETE?

Comment: of course, it's the same url and the same .php file: GET xxxxxx.com/php/customers.php?_dc=1417023448549&db=107&page=2&start=25&limit=25 200 OK 1.68s

Comment: Did you configure PUT and DELETE as allowed verbs in your IIS?  Also, what is _dc?  Between the GET and the PUT, the query strings are different.

Comment: It just a random number it's exists in every request just to force the browser to load everything and not caching (it's sencha not me), as you can see I edited my orginal question and I have enabled these verbs in my web.config and applicationHost.config

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the problem is happening, but I'm very wary about your URL.  In the GET call, you have `xxxxxx.com/php/customers.php?_dc=1417023448549&db=107&page=2&start=25&limit=25` as your URL.  Just to explain, and not to insult you if you already know this, but the query string is how the server references which object to return in the response.  These values include `_dc=1417023448549&db=107&page=2&start=25&limit=25` for the GET request.  So the server knows that the GET request wants the object whose _dc value is 1417023448549, db value is 107, and so on.  When you have the PUT request, you have `xxxxxx.com/php/customers.php/13?_dc=1417022337273`.  I'm not sure as to why there is another `/` after customers.php.  That says that customers.php is another directory.  You said sencha is creating the URLs.  My guess is that you configured it incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: I don't have control on sencha code, I have seen it that way with '/' but the exact code works fine in my laptop !

Answer (score 0):

Here you can run it in your browser and you could use firebug to see results:

**roya4u.com/roya_se_mobile**

Try to edit contact and then hit the "**GREEN**" button (**save**)

WHEN I COPY THE LINK FROM FIREBUG TO NEW TAB IN THE BROWSER IT WORKS:

```
http://roya4u.com/Roya_SE_Mobile/php/customers.php/13?_dc=1417027029131
```

I GET A RESPOND !!!

that is very weird??